# How to display image in class that extends SKSpriteNode?

Tags: cocoa, sprite-kit, skspritenode, xamarin.mac

I want to show image on scene by using the class that extends SKSpriteNode

```
public class ImageNode : SKSpriteNode
{
    public override void TouchesBeganWithEvent(NSEvent theEvent)
    {
        base.TouchesBeganWithEvent(theEvent);

        var point = theEvent.LocationInNode(this);
        var touchNode = this.GetNodeAtPoint(point);
    }
}
```

I am calling this class in SKScene as

```
Image = new ImageNode();
Image.Size = new CGSize(20, 20);
```

but image not displaying on screen!

Comment: The title and the content of your question do not appear to match. Do you want to set the name of the image or do you want to display the image. Also, what language is your code? C# (based on the xamarin.mac connection)?

Comment: I am trying in xamarin.mac, I have to show an image on screen with that ImageNode class